# How to improve performance of a method

Tags: c#, wcf, c#-4.0, entity-framework-4

I have a pretty big method.
where i have some c# calculation and also i am calling 3/4 stored procedures.
constructing 3/4 objects and finally adding in a list and returning the list.

My target is to improve the performance of this method so that it takes less time to execute.

My question is, is there any way so that I can check each part of the method and find out which part is taking time to execute??
may be some looging or something !!

I am using LINQ to EF.

Comment: The `Stopwatch` class might be of interest to you if you want to log it. Also, if there is a bit you believe might be a problem post it up and someone might see why it is running slow.

Comment: You could always time each section of code separately, but this looks like a great situation to use sample profiling.

Comment: why dont get your code on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Invest in a performance profiler, like [Ants from Redgate](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/ants-performance-profiler/). Some of the better versions of Visual Studio also come with one.

At the least, you could try using [System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.aspx)

From msdn:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Stopwatch stopWatch = new Stopwatch();
    stopWatch.Start();
    Thread.Sleep(10000);
    stopWatch.Stop();
    TimeSpan ts = stopWatch.Elapsed;

    string elapsedTime = String.Format("{0:00}:{1:00}:{2:00}.{3:00}",
        ts.Hours, ts.Minutes, ts.Seconds,
        ts.Milliseconds / 10);

    Console.WriteLine("RunTime " + elapsedTime);
}
```

Comment: Stopwatch is the first option to choose if you think that something is slower than it should be.

Answer (score 3):

If possible, you can try executing your stored procedures in parallel.  I've seen this improve performance quite a bit, especially if your stored procedures just do reads and no writes.

It might look something like this:

```
ConcurrentBag<Result> results = new ConcurrentBag<Result>();

Parallel.Invoke(
                () => {
                    var db = new DatabaseEntities();  
                    Result result1 = db.StoredProcudure1();
                    results.Add(result1);
                }
                () => {
                    var db = new DatabaseEntities();  
                    Result result2 = db.StoredProcudure2();
                    results.Add(result2);
                }
                () => {
                    var db = new DatabaseEntities();  
                    Result result3 = db.StoredProcudure3();
                    results.Add(result3);
                }
);

return results;
```

I'm using a `ConcurrentBag` here instead of a `List` because it is thread safe.

Comment: Nice one! Really like this! +1

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is a profiler - a profiler runs your program and tells you how much time each line of code took to execute, as well as how long it took to execute as a percentage of the total execution time.

A great C# profiler is the [ANTS .Net Profiler](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/ants-performance-profiler/), it's rather expensive, but it has a 14 day free trial - I think this would be perfect for your needs.

Answer (score 1):

You have several options.  I find myself using stop watches to test this kind of thing.  Howerver before you do anything are you sure the code isn't already performing well enough.  If it ain't broke don't fix it is often the best advice.  If you're still interested you can do this kind of thing:

```
Stopwatch sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();

// do some code stuff here

sw.Stop();

Console.WriteLine(sw.ElapsedTicks);
```

You also have seconds, milliseconds and other measurements in the sw variable.

Comment: Thanks. I will try it. It is a wcf and the client is iPhone. It is returning data in around 3 seconds but the requirement is to make it more faster..

Answer (score 1):

My advise would be for you to use [JetBrains dottrace](http://www.jetbrains.com/profiler/) it have some very helpfull functionality that points hotspot and tells you which piece of code have taken how long

PS: it has saved my neck few times

Answer (score 0):

Database accesses are generally orders of magnitude slower than any calculations that you might make (unless you are trying the predict tomorrows weather). So the LINQ-to-EF part is most probably where time gets lost.

You can use profilers to analyse a program. SQL-Server has a profiler that allows you to monitor queries. If you want to analyse the code, google for .NET profilers and you will find quite a few that have a free licence. Or buy one, if you find it useful. The [EQATEC profiler](http://eqatec.com/Profiler/) was quite useful for me.

If you have a big method your code is badly structured. Making a big method does not make it faster than splitting it into smaller logical parts. Smaller parts will be easier to maintain and the code profilers will yield more useful informations, since they often only return method call totals and don't show the times for single lines of code.